# Restore single project in TFS

Tags: tfs, backup, restore

I accidentally deleted a team project from TFS using the WFE yesterday. I thought I was just deleting the unused kanban board.... durr.

I would like to restore this single project, without a full database restore.

Is this possible?

Work items and checkins have since been added to other projects in TFS so I would rather not do a full restore if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no complete way of doing this. What you could do is restore your backup to a new collection (a clone) and get rid of the other projects, but you would still have the restored Team Project in a separate collection.

There are some tools for migrating a team project to another collection, but as far as I have heard these are not optimal solutions. [Microsoft is planning](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te) on making it possible to move a Team project from one collection to another, so at some point you might be able to move the Team project back home.

Comment: Hi Tore, thanks for replying. I will try your solution this evening.